# Storing an "n" number of Queues in an Array

Tags: java, arrays, queue

Is it possible to store an "n" number of Queues in an Array in Java? So for example say I had Queue objects: Queue1, Queue2, and Queue3.  Could you store these 3 Queue objects in an Array?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are `Queue1`, `Queue2`, and `Queue3` declared simply as `Queue`, or as `Queue<T>` for some type `T`; and if the second one, do all three have the same `T`?

Answer (score 0):

`Queue[] queue = new Queue[] { Queue1, Queue2, Queue3 };`

Answer (score 0):

```
Queue<Whatever> queue0 = new Queue<Whatever>();
Queue<Whatever> queue1 = new Queue<Whatever>();
ArrayList<Queue<Whatever>> queueAL = new ArrayList<Queue<Whatever>>();
queueAL.add(queue0);
queueAL.add(queue1);
```

Comment: Why to use use 'Whatever' for Queue? 

Queue is an object in his class.

Comment: Whatever is the type of the objects contained by the queues

Comment: Kewl. It's always a good practice to write this way. Good job +1

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

If you are sure about number of Queue objects to be in the `Array`, then you can proceed as:

```
Queue[] queue = new Queue[10];
```

But,
If you are not sure about number of Queues, then I would suggest you use `ArrayList` instead of 
using an `array`.

`ArrayList` is a dynamic array implementation in Java. Highly flexible and efficient to work with.

Import it using :

`import java.util.ArrayList;`

Hope this helps.